# How do I generate a vector of random numbers in a range?

Tags: vector, random, rust

How do I generate a vector of 100 64-bit integer values in the range from 1 to 20, allowing duplicates?

Comment: Generate one and keep on going. /halfserious

Comment: Like ' let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101);'? I could make a closure out of it and map it to a vector for 1..100?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are a few main pieces that you need here. First, how to create a vector of 100 calculated items? The easiest way is to create a range of 100 and map over those items. For instance you could do:

```
let vals: Vec<u64> = (0..100).map(|v| v + 1000).collect();
// [1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, ...
```

Splitting this up:

1. [`0..100`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html) creates an iterator for 0 through 99
2. [`.map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) processes each item in the iterator when the iterator is processed.
3. [`.collect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) takes an iterator and converts it into any type that implements [`FromIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html) which in your case is `Vec`.

Expanding on this for your random values, you can adjust the `.map` function to generate a random value from 0 to 20 using the `rand` crate's `gen_range` function to create a numeric value within a given range.

```
use rand::Rng; // 0.6.5

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    let vals: Vec<u64> = (0..100).map(|_| rng.gen_range(0, 20)).collect();

    println!("{:?}", vals);
}
```

([On the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c10dc19e1be5986622a39ebce16e5b4b))

You should also consider using the [`rand::distributions::Uniform`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.5/rand/distributions/uniform/struct.Uniform.html) type to create the range up front, which is is more efficient than calling `gen_range` multiple times, then pull samples from it 100 times:

```
use rand::{distributions::Uniform, Rng}; // 0.6.5

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let range = Uniform::new(0, 20);

    let vals: Vec<u64> = (0..100).map(|_| rng.sample(&range)).collect();

    println!("{:?}", vals);
}
```

([On the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d6fb38e5672e2a66fca0e9721046006d))

Answer (score 14):

TL;DR:

```
use rand::{distributions::Uniform, Rng}; // 0.8.0

fn main() {
    let range = Uniform::from(0..20);
    let values: Vec<u64> = rand::thread_rng().sample_iter(&range).take(100).collect();
    println!("{:?}", values);
}
```

It's important to use [`rand::distributions::uniform::Uniform`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.0/rand/distributions/uniform/struct.Uniform.html) instead of simply performing the modulo of a uniform random number. See [Why do people say there is modulo bias when using a random number generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10984974/155423) for more details.

Since we are generating multiple numbers from a range, it's more performant to create the `Uniform` once and reuse it. Creating the `Uniform` does some computation to avoid sampling bias.

We can use [`Rng::sample_iter`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.0/rand/trait.Rng.html#method.sample_iter) to create an iterator of random values and then `take` some number of them, collecting into a `Vec`. `collect` will even make use of `Iterator::size_hint` to allocate exactly the right number of elements.

---

If you only needed a *single* random number in the range, you could use the shortcut [`Rng::gen_range`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.0/rand/trait.Rng.html#method.gen_range):

```
use rand::Rng; // 0.8.0

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let value: u64 = rng.gen_range(0..20);
}
```

If you needed a vector of random values without limiting to a range, you can use the `Standard` distribution:

```
use rand::{distributions::Standard, Rng}; // 0.8.0

fn main() {
    let values: Vec<u64> = rand::thread_rng().sample_iter(Standard).take(100).collect();
    println!("{:?}", values);
}
```

Comment: Could be `rng.gen_iter::<u64>().take(100).map(|n| n % 20 + 1).collect();` with only std.

Comment: @Stargateur You might at least note that `% 20` is not the same as `gen_range(0, 20)` - and I'd really advise against "cheating" on this level, even if for specific use cases it might not matter.

Comment: @Stefan What do you mean, I'm not cheating, this is how all ranges are implemented, https://doc.rust-lang.org/rand/src/rand/distributions/range.rs.html#127. This is very classic.

Comment: @Stargateur Just read the comment and the `accept_zone` condition above the line you just linked to see the difference.

Comment: The `accept_zone` calculation is the reason why you should allocate [`Range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rand/rand/distributions/range/struct.Range.html) once and reuse it, instead of calling [`gen_range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rand/rand/trait.Rng.html#method.gen_range) in a loop.