# How to populate a vector with predefined capacity?

Tags: rust

I am trying to populate a vector after initialising it with `with_capacity()` as the number of elements is known prior to its creation and it seems more efficient with it.

The following code does NOT populate with random values AT ALL: `println!("{}", v.len());` outputs zero.

```
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    const NUMBER_OF_RANDOM_NUMBERS: usize = 10;

    let mut v = Vec::with_capacity(NUMBER_OF_RANDOM_NUMBERS);

    for i in &mut v {
        *i += rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 2^32);
    }

    println!("{}", v.len());
}
```

My thinking is after `let mut v = Vec::with_capacity(NUMBER_OF_RANDOM_NUMBERS)` a brand new vector gets initialised with 10 zeros and then using `rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 2^32)` to insert, or should I say, add a random number to each zero.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Capacity =/= length. I cannot find the duplicate right now.

Comment: `gen_range(1, 2^32);` does not do what you think it does (xor vs pow)

Comment: Take a look at the implementation for [`Vec::with_capacity(usize)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec.rs.html#356-361), it sets the `len` to 0, therefore making it UB to access any value in the `Vec`

Comment: *it seems more efficient* — yes, which is why `Iterator::collect` makes sure to allocate the correct space up front. Use one of the solutions from [How do I generate a vector of random numbers in a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48218459/155423). These are additionally efficient because they do not create the RNG multiple times and do not repeatedly generate the range to pick inside.

Comment: @hellow - Thank you very much for pointing that out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51208703/how-to-raise-a-number-to-a-power tells me exactly that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`with_capacity` does not initialize the values of the vector, it just allocates space for them. From [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.with_capacity):

> It is important to note that although the returned vector has the
>   capacity specified, the vector will have a zero length. For an
>   explanation of the difference between length and capacity, see
>   [Capacity and reallocation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#capacity-and-reallocation).

This means that when your loop code is executed, there are no items in the vector, and therefore it loops a total of zero times. Resulting in no change in the vector.