# Is there a way to store a random number generator as a trait object?

Tags: rust, traits, trait-objects

Is there a way to hold a generic random number generator in Rust?  I'd like a way to write a generic piece of code such as:

```
use rand::Rng; // 0.7.2

fn main() {
    // Purely random numbers on the interval 0 to 1
    println!("Pure random");
    let mut rng: Box<dyn rand::Rng> = Box::new(rand::thread_rng());
    for i in 0..10 {
        println!("{}", rng.gen::<f64>());
    }
    println!("");

    // On a seed
    *rng = rand::SeedableRng::seed_from_u64(0);
    for i in 0..10 {
        println!("{}", rng.gen::<f64>());
    }
    println!("");
}
```

The variable `rng` holds different kinds of random number generators using a seed or otherwise.  However, there's a whole host of errors with this code such as:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `rand::Rng` cannot be made into an object
 --> src/main.rs:6:18
  |
6 |     let mut rng: Box<dyn rand::Rng> = Box::new(rand::thread_rng());
  |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `rand::Rng` cannot be made into an object
  |
  = note: method `gen` has generic type parameters
  = note: method `gen_range` has generic type parameters
  = note: method `sample` has generic type parameters
  = note: method `fill` has generic type parameters
  = note: method `try_fill` has generic type parameters
```

As such, what's the correct way to hold a random number generator so that it can be replaced with another?  Basically, I would like to generate purely random numbers, but then replace the generator with one using a seed for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use [`RngCore`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.7.2/rand/trait.RngCore.html) for your trait object, not [`Rng`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.7.2/rand/trait.Rng.html):

```
use rand::{Rng, RngCore, SeedableRng}; // 0.7.2
use rand_chacha::ChaCha20Rng; // 0.2.1

fn main() {
    let mut rng: Box<dyn RngCore>;

    rng = Box::new(rand::thread_rng());
    for _ in 0..10 {
        println!("{}", rng.gen::<f64>());
    }

    println!();

    rng = Box::new(ChaCha20Rng::seed_from_u64(42));
    for _ in 0..10 {
        println!("{}", rng.gen::<f64>());
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Are polymorphic variables allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28219519/155423)
- [Unable to create a polymorphic type because the trait cannot be made into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39412626/155423)
- [The trait cannot be made into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45116984/155423)
- [Understanding Traits and Object Safety](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44096235/155423)
- [How do I generate a vector of random numbers in a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48218459/155423)

#### Other points

- `rand::SeedableRng::seed_from_u64` doesn't make any sense because you have never specified a concrete type to implement the trait object.
- > Purely random numbers

  Both generators are pseudo-random number generators and produce the same kind of numbers; one isn't "more random" than the other.